# Is this kibble or poison?

Tags: dogs, safety, poison

I was walking my dog in a park (respecting social distancing and all). At some point I heard a crack; she had picked up a very dry pellet from the grass and was chewing on it.

I couldn't get her to spit. I then looked at the pellets and they seemed small. If these are kibbles I don't recognize the brand. I'm worried now because one of my neighbours had told me that a few years ago some heartless person wanted to poison the squirrels in the park and ended up poisoning many dogs, some of which died.

I took pictures of the pellets, they look like this:

[image: Something which I can't tell whether it's a kibble or rat poison]

[image: Something which I can't tell whether it's a kibble or rat poison]

Is anyone able to tell whether these are kibbles or rat poison?

P.S.: My dog is fine now, not showing any signs on intoxication, though I know that rat poison can take a few days to take effect. I am going to contact a vet clinic now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to definitively know from only a photo, especially as even if it is kibble, there's no guarantee it hasn't been poisoned; you may need to contact a local poison control center and give them a sample to test.

Comment: the holes in the middle makes me think this might be toxic bait of some kind,my best advice is to contact your vet and to start treatment as soon as possible https://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/pet-safety-tips/mouse-and-rat-poison-rodenticides-poisonous-to-dogs-cats/

Comment: @trondhansen - Isn't that a bit like saying Cheerios are suspicious because they have a hole in the middle? Some kibble has holes. Any kibble can be turned into poison.

Comment: if it is poison the hole is there to put them on a string to hold the bait in one place,i have used wax blocks to get rid of mice and rats in my house and they all have holes in the blocks.

Comment: @trondhansen - Thanks, I did not know that! That's what I get for having cats (and dogs). No mice.